# django custom filter works only without registering?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm following tutorial on the custom django filter and really can't explain what's going on.Here's the code in template.

```
{% load filters %}
{{ entry.language|cut:"blabla" }
```

and here's the filter

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def cut(value, arg):
    return value.replace(arg, '')

register.filter('cut', cut)
```

Strange thing is, that I'm getting this error

```
AttributeError
'Language' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

But If I remove register filter function  `register.filter('cut', cut)` , there is no error, and filter actually runs? What's actually going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a built-in filter [`cut`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#cut).

Yours has the problem that if the parameter is not a string, it will fail. The built-in version presumably converts to a string before calling `replace()`. Use that instead.